# How to generate csv file using apache camel and mybatis/bindy?

Tags: apache-camel

I am trying to generate csv file by exporting data from db through apache camel and mybatis/bindy. I am able to get result set and CSV file is generated, but the csv file is missing column name. How can I generate a CSV file with column name added along with the rows.

Comment: What code do you have so far? Can you add it to the question?

Comment: Which Camel Version?